# How can I connect a Lumia 950 XL to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, windows-10, usb, lumia-950-xl

My Lumia 950 XL appears with a yellow exclamation mark in Windows 10 Device Manager and Windows is convinced that it cannot find a driver for it. Oddly enough the connection did work a week ago. What am I doing wrong and what happened to the driver?

[image: Yellow exclamation mark]
[image: Cannot find driver]

Comment: For me, going to Devices and Printers (with the phone unplugged), then right-clicking on the phone and choosing "Remove Device", then plugging it back in fixed it sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

Try uninstalling the driver and connecting the phone.

1. Open Device manager
2. Right click on the phone.

[image]

3. Click Uninstall.
4. Reconnect your phone.

Comment: That causes the behaviour described above when the phone appears with a yellow exclamation mark and Device Manager cannot find the driver.

Comment: See USB option in settings.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to install the [Windows Device Recovery Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-device-recovery-tool-faq). This should automatically install all required drivers for your phone.

Comment: Interesting tool. I will check if it does anything for me and my phone. Ta.

Comment: Actually using the tool will reset your phone, though.

Comment: I have the same problem with my HP Elite X3. I tried to use the device recovery tool, without effect. The strange thing is that the elite X3 does connect to another laptop.

Comment: @user25028 Have you tried out the other two answers here?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue after Win 10 anniversary update.  Plugging phone into USB 3 hub would not recognize the phone (even though it worked before the update).  I tried plugging it directly into a USB port on the MB and it recognized the phone, installed the drivers, and connected.  AFTER this, I was able to connect via the USB 3 hub, as I had before the update.  Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Have to try something like this. Ta.

Comment: Had a similar problem. Even though they worked for months, some days ago, Windows decided that it didn't like my PC's front USB ports anymore. Plugging the phone into one of the back ports finally worked. Obviously. /s